# Return INT from T-SQL not evaluating in Published Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net

Running into an issue in which I have coded something which works in my sandbox, including when pointing to an external database but does not work in my published environment.

What I am trying to do is get a INT result from a stored procedure. I have tried having the procedure return the INT and also set it as an OUTPUT parameter with no luck in either case. Note, again this works in my own sandbox, but not in our published environments, deployed using the Visual Studio deploy functionality.

Here is the C# evaluating the Integer return code:

```
var returnVal = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int)
{
    IsNullable = true,
    Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
};



var sqlParams = new List<SqlParameter>
{
    new SqlParameter("@Host", dataEntryModel.Host),
    new SqlParameter("@PurchaseOrderNumberUser", dataEntryModel.PurchaseOrderNumberUser),
    new SqlParameter("@PharmacyId", dataEntryModel.BatchUploadPharmacyId),
    new SqlParameter("@NDCTable", table),
    new SqlParameter("@LastModifiedById", dataEntryModel.LastModifiedById),
    new SqlParameter("@POSourceTypeId", dataEntryModel.PurchaseOrderSourceType),
    new SqlParameter("@PoId", dataEntryModel.PurchaseOrderId),
    returnVal
};

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Database.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand("AdminApp._spBatchUploadNDCToPurchaseOrder"))
    {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParams.ToArray());
                 // Setting command timeout to 120 second - Added by Tom Miller 10-31-14
                 command.CommandTimeout = 600;
        command.ExecuteScalar();
        returnPurchaseOrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(command.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);
    }
}           
return returnPurchaseOrderNumber;
```

I am not sure why this is not working in other environments. I have pointed my sandbox to the Development database used in my deployed environment and it appears at runtime the return code being evaluated is 0, which is incorrect.

**Resolved** After some testing, I was completely off direction. My data was being set correctly but the data layout when pulling in DEV varied due to poor architecture on the SQL side. Thank you and apologize for the time.

Comment: is this actually accessible outside of the using `returnPurchaseOrderNumber ` I would declare this outside of it so that this line will be valid `return returnPurchaseOrderNumber` declare the variable outside the using initially this is not declared as well `"@ReturnValue"`

Comment: I can confirm it is. The returnPurchaseOrderNumber is declared above and thus accessible.

Comment: Also, making a comment. This should be an ExecuteNonQuery. There is no row selected. It originally was this, but apparently the code I pasted was after tinkering.

Comment: Not if my direction = ReturnValue. That would be valid if I were doing an output parameter. Note i have done a variation of this code in which I used an output parameter and it is yielding the same results.

Comment: yes I just noticed that.. ignore my previous comment sorry about that

Comment: Please start by updating the question with code that 1) Is verified to work in dev env 2) Is verified to be the same in the published env 3) Does not work there. Then show us relevant parts of the stored procedure (the part dealing with the return value/output parameter/resultset). Right now there is too much guesswork needed...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the result the wrong way. Try this:

```
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: This would have not worked with the code I had at the time, but it is also my fault for pasting the code with an ExecuteScalar. My code was not executing a query and thus the Execute Scalar would not work.

I modified do a select on the code set and thus yield a result for execute scalar as opposed to the return code. I am having the same issues, which is leading me to believe I am looking at this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`command` doesn't have a parameter called `@ReturnValue`. [EDIT: sorry, yes it does, see comments]  Set a breakpoint and check, but it is probably evaluating as `null`, and attempting to convert `null` to an integer.  I would expect that to throw an exception, but if it doesn't, it would evaluate to the default integer value, which is 0.

If your stored procedure is returning a value, then use NicoRiff's approach and assign the result of `ExecuteScalar()` to a variable.  If it is using an output parameter, then give it one to use.  Declare an output parameter like this:

```
new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
```

Comment: I am capturing the return value successfully by setting the direction of this parameter as return. If I cast a breakpoint in my sandbox this works correctly and I have no problem whatsoever.

I have also noted that I have attempted to make @ReturnValue and OUTPUT parameter, actually I made PoId an Inputoutput parameter yielding the same result. It works in my local sandbox but does not work in my deployed environment.

Comment: When you say that you are setting the direction of the parameter as return, are you doing that in your stored proc, or in your C# code?  If you are doing it in C#, it is not shown in your code sample.  If you are setting it in your stored proc, then I am unfamiliar with that approach, but it is probably just returning that value.  If that's the case, then `command.ExecuteScalar()` returns an `object` that you can cast as an integer - NicoRiff's answer shows this approach.

Comment: var returnVal = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int)
    {
        IsNullable = true,
        Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue
    };

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  My apologies.  Well you can still try capturing the value returned by `command.ExecuteScalar()`, or you can try changing that line to `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` if you aren't expecting it to return a value.  At a quick glance, that part of the code looks funny.  You can also try changing the parameter direction to `.Output`, as I have used that approach successfully.  I understand that all of this "should work" but since it "doesn't work," we need to try something new.  You may have a different SQL Server version in your sandbox or something else that would explain this...

Comment: Thank you for the input. I think it looks funny because I have been tinkering for a while. An alternative I have tried is making my Parameter PoId an InputOutput and then setting the parameter in the SQL code. This again works in my sandbox but not in my deployed environment.

I will clean my code up as I figure out the issue! Appreciate the help!